# jquery not iterating over json

Tags: jquery, json

Im not sure why this json wont iterate...

I have

html

```
<input type="hidden" value="[{"drop":54,"colour":532,"chosen":830}]" name="HiddenOpenerJson" id="HiddenOpenerJson">
```

jquery:

```
$('#OpenerDirectionVal').change(function () {
    var selected = this.value;
    var dataArray = $("#HiddenOpenerJson").val();
    $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(dataArray))).each(function () {
        var drop = this.drop;
        var colour = this.colour;
        var chosen = this.chosen;
        if (chosen == selected) {
            $("select[data-hardwareid='" + drop + "']").val(colour);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think your `value` is wrong. what does it say on the console?

Comment: @cr0ss yes think you're right, getting  Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [{"drop":54,"colour":532,"chosen":830}] - is this invalid json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML code is incorrect, so the value in the input will just be cut at the first quotation mark, so you get just `"[{"`.

You need to HTML encode the JSON:

```
<input type="hidden" value="[{&quot;drop&quot;:54,&quot;colour&quot;:532,&quot;chosen&quot;:830}]" name="HiddenOpenerJson" id="HiddenOpenerJson">
```

Then, when you want to parse the string into JSON, you don't want to encode the JSON into JSON, just parse it:

```
$(jQuery.parseJSON(dataArray)).each(function () {
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xUhxE/

Comment: im now getting SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Comment: @raklos: There is something in the value that is not correctly encoded. The string in the example works fine, so you just need to follow the same pattern to encode it when you have more items in the array. If you can show the exact code that you are using, I can help you pinpoint the problem.